# Codeigniter PHP JSON sends HTML response

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a problem with Codeigniter and JSON. Here is my coding:

```
$.post("Admin/Admin/addschool", {test: 'test'}, function(data){             
  if (data.status == 'ok')
    alert(data);
  else 
    alert(data);
}, "json");
```

... and in my controller:

```
public function addschool() {
  $data = array("status" => "ok", "message"=> "something ");  
  echo json_encode($data);  
  exit(); 
}
```

But each time my json reply with the HTML of my whole view e.g my response

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:10090/css/layout.css" />
<title>Administration</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
</head>
```

Comment: try to run this function in your browser url bar. Check what it returns. And also try to use function(data,status,xhr).

Comment: Try `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));exit();`

Comment: Do you have some views in controller's constructor?

Comment: The file that contains the ajax call, what is it's path ? You may want `/Admin/Admin/addschool` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is good practice not to you used "echo", and you use the 'return'. Try to put down the controller directly to url and see if your return json

Comment: He's not returning anything though, he's `echoing` it out to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try use absolute URL

```
$.post("/Admin/Admin/addschool", {test: 'test'}, function(data){             
  if (data.status == 'ok')
    alert(data);
  else 
    alert(data);
}, "json");
```

And it is better return then exit inside codeigniter function

```
public function addschool() {
  $data = array("status" => "ok", "message"=> "something ");  
  echo json_encode($data);  
  return; 
}
```

Comment: codeigniter is automatically send html (layout) for every requests. he want to disable that thing, not what your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a problem with the url. Let me give u an example of url routing problem

Lets say, the admin controller index function loads the admin home page, so in the load method, in the url part, if u just write "addschool", the ajax call will go to addschool function.

A chaining is done automatically, admin/addschool

But say for example, the function admin/load_view 
loads ur view page, now if u type addschool in the url, chaining will take place, and the url will become

admin/load_view/addschool

So you have to check the codeigniter function that is loading the view page, then use the appropriate chaining